# How to enable swagger UI on micronaut?

Tags: kotlin, swagger, micronaut

I'm following the micronaut doc for openapi at https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-openapi/latest/guide/
and the UI is not being generated, every time when I try to access `/swagger`, `/swagger-ui` I got this error:

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "/swagger",
      "templated": false
    }
  },
  "_embedded": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Page Not Found"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The dependencies are installed:

```
implementation("io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations")
annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.openapi:micronaut-openapi:4.5.2")
```

The router on `application.yml` is defined:

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: myapp
  router:
    static-resources:
      default:
        enabled: true
      swagger:
        enabled: true
        paths: classpath:META-INF/swagger
        mapping: /swagger/**
```

and the file `openapi.properties` on the root folder is created:

```
swagger-ui.enabled=true
micronaut.openapi.views.spec=apidoc.enabled=true,swagger-ui.enabled=true,swagger-ui.theme=flattop
micronaut.openapi.expand.api.version=v0.1
micronaut.openapi.expand.openapi.description=myapp
```

according to the docs a `.yml` file should be generated at;

> For Kotlin build/tmp/kapt3/classes/main/META-INF/swagger/myapp-0.1.yml

On my controllers I have the `Operation` and `ApiResponses` annotation as well, but when I run the application the file `yml` is not being generated, how can I properly enable swagger on my micronaut project?

> Code sample: https://github.com/rafa-acioly/micronaut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined only `swagger` in your `application.yml`. You should add also add a section for `swagger-ui` with a similar definition:

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: openapitest
  router:
    static-resources:
      swagger:
        paths: classpath:META-INF/swagger
        mapping: /swagger/**
      swagger-ui:
        paths: classpath:META-INF/swagger/views/swagger-ui
        mapping: /swagger-ui/**
```

Also, I used the default `openapi.properties` file:

```
swagger-ui.enabled=true
redoc.enabled=false
rapidoc.enabled=false
rapidoc.bg-color=#14191f
rapidoc.text-color=#aec2e0
rapidoc.sort-endpoints-by=method
```

And did you try to `clean` and `build` your project with `gradlew`?

I create a sample [repository](https://github.com/jz36/openapitest) on GitHub and you can check it.

=========UPDATE========

Ok, I've found what is incorrect! You are using `annotation-processing` :

```
annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.openapi:micronaut-openapi:4.5.2")
```

But if you are using Kotlin, you should use `kapt` - Kotlin Annotation Processing Tool. Here is a few articles - [link1](https://mdapp.medium.com/annotation-processing-with-kapt-and-gradle-237793f2be57), [link2](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kapt.html).

So you should change to:

```
kapt("io.micronaut.openapi:micronaut-openapi:4.5.2")
```

Comment: The `yml` files are not being generated, I've also used the `swagger-ui` on the `router`, cleaned and build again, and the result is the same

Comment: @RafaAcioly could you upload your code to GitHub? Because I am still getting openapitest-0.0.yml

Or please provide full `application.yml` and `build.gradle` files

Comment: I've added the source code on the question :)

Comment: Thank you for your update, the page is now being found but the assets are not, every `.css` and `.js` is gettint `404`

Comment: This is really strange. I've just checked it out on my computer and everything is fine. Can you locate `.css` and `.js` files under `build/tmp/kapt3/classes/main/META-INF/swagger/views/swagger-ui/res`?